# Can't make UISlider go between Left: -0 to -50 and Right: 0 to 50

Tags: xcode, scroll, uislider

My slider current is 50. If I scroll right. I suppose to get -0 to - 50. If scroll right I suppose to get 0 to 50. I don't need 1 to 100.

Help.

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

    if ([myLabel.text length] > 50){
      // Make - 0 to -50 
      myLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", -(int)sender.value];
    }else  if ([myLabel.text length] < 50){   
      // Make 0 to 50
      myLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)sender.value];
    }else{
      myLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)sender.value];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set slider min Max:

```
        slider.maximumValue = 100;
        slider.minimumValue = 0;
        slider.value = 50;
```

for Action

```
- (void)sliderMoved:(id)sender  {
        //DLog(@"slider moved");
        UISlider*timeSlider = (UISlider*)sender;
        if (timeSlider.value < 0)   {
            timeSlider.value = -50;
        }
        else if (timeSlider.value < 30) {
            timeSlider.value = -30;
        }
        else if (timeSlider.value < 50) {
            timeSlider.value = 0;
        }
        else if (timeSlider.value < 80) {
            timeSlider.value = 30;
        }
        else if (timeSlider.value < 100)    {
            timeSlider.value = 50;
        }

        else    {
            timeSlider.value = 0;
        }
        _chosenDuration = timeSlider.value;
        [_timeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"time%@", nil) , _chosenDuration]];
    }
```

Set all condition What you want ......